# Bubble sort complexity calculation, unsure how it went from one step to another.

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity

I'm looking at my textbooks steps for calculating the complexity of bubble sort...and it jumps a step where I don't know what exactly they did.

[image]

I see everything up to that point using summation rules and all, but am unsure about that jump. Any help on explaining more how they got that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{i = 0}^{n-2} (n - 1 -i) = (n -1) + (n-2) + ... + 2 + 1 = \frac{(n -1)n}{2}$$

It is the sum of the simplest arithmetic series.

Answer (score 1):

Plug in the possible values of $i$ into the summation!  You get:
$$
(n-1) + (n-2) + \cdots + 2 + 1
$$
which is the sum of consecutive integers from 1 to $(n-1)$.  This sum has a well-known formula:
$$
{(\mbox {last term})\cdot(\mbox{last term} + 1)\over 2}={(n-1)n\over 2}
$$